# App Language Help Default Language gets back when App is

Tags: android

Hi I'm making GymExercise App and I add two Languages

1.English
2.Macedonian

Also, I add Menu so user can choose what language he wants after he choseelanguage (example Macedonian) Language will be changed if I open other Activity or Fragment but when I close the app language go to default English I want to stay the Language that user chossed How can I do that?

Thanks

MainActivity.java

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.language_en:
                Locale locale = new Locale("en");
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                Toast.makeText(this, "You choosed English Language", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case R.id.language_mk:
                Locale locale2 = new Locale("mk");
                Locale.setDefault(locale2);
                Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
                config2.locale = locale2;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Одбравте Македонски Јазик", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.language_en:
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Toast.makeText(this, "You choosed English Language", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            saveLocale("en");
            break;

        case R.id.language_mk:
            Locale locale2 = new Locale("mk");
            Locale.setDefault(locale2);
            Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
            config2.locale = locale2;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Одбравте Македонски Јазик", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            saveLocale("mk");
            break;

    }
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void saveLocale(String language) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.PREFERENCES", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("USER_LANGUAGE", language);
    editor.commit();
}
```

When you change language then need to refresh. 
Write this code after change language,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Store Language code in **SharedPreference**.

Create **ChangeLanguageApplication** class,

```
public class ChangeLanguageApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.PREFERENCES", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Locale locale = new Locale(sharedPreferences.getString("USER_LANGUAGE","en"));//Get from Pref.

        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

    }
}
```

Define in  **Manifest** file,

```
<application android:name=".ChangeLanguageApplication"> </application>
```

Comment: Thank you for that :) Now when i close the app langauge go to default English i want to stay the Language that user chossed How can i do that ?

Comment: i will check later currently i'm out

Comment: check post bellow

Answer (score 0):

@Bhavya Gandhi

Here what i do doesnt work

MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.language_en:
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Toast.makeText(this, "You choosed English Language", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.language_mk:
            Locale locale2 = new Locale("mk");
            Locale.setDefault(locale2);
            Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
            config2.locale = locale2;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Одбравте Македонски Јазик", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

    }
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void saveLocale(String language) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.PREFERENCES", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("USER_LANGUAGE", language);
    editor.commit();
}
```

ChangeLanguageApplication Class

```
package com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Aleksandar on 28.2.2018.
 */

public class ChangeLanguageApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Locale locale = new Locale("USER_LANGUAGE");//Get from Pref.
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:name=".ChangeLanguageApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.QrActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.Hristijan.Aleksandar.GymAssistant.Exercises.BmiActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: saveLocale where you call this method?

Comment: Locale locale = new Locale("USER_LANGUAGE");
Update this line get language code form pref.

Comment: i didn't understand this part of code
Locale locale = new Locale("your language code");//Get from Pref.,what i need to change here "your language code"? i tried to change example to mk but it goes default Macedonian Language ....